# Why isn't this animation of system of balls and springs working well?

Tags: java, processing

I want to animate a system of N balls on springs in Processing.The system looks like this for N=3:[image: This]

The balls' movement can be described by the following system differential equations:
[image: Equation]
Where m is the mass of the ball, k is the 'strength' of the spring and u_n is the displacement of the n-th ball from its equilibrium. And there are also a 0th and an N+1th ball, with u_0=0 and u_(N+1)=0.

I think this is the most important part of my code:

```
  tempu = u;
  tempv = v;
  for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++){
    a[i] = (k/m)*(u[i-1]+u[i+1]-2*u[i]);
    tempv[i] += a[i];
    tempv[i] += a[i];
    tempu[i] += tempv[i];
    tempu[i] += tempv[i];
  }
  u = tempu;
  v = tempv;
  for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    ellipse(original[i] + u[i], d, 10, 10);
  }
```

First, I fill u, v, and a with 0s at the beginning, and then modify 1 u to let the system move. (It's all happening in the setup). It's working well for N=1, but for higher N, it's getting out of the control and moving out of the screen really fast. I was checking the N=2 situation with low fps, and the 2 balls were not moving symmetrically.

**Question:** Why isn't it working well?

Comment: Without a [mcve] it’s difficult to match your code to your formula, but my guess is that you have incorrectly assumed `tempu = u;` creates a copy of the `u` array.  It does not.  Arrays are objects, so tempu and u refer to exactly the same array.  If you want to make a copy of the array, try `tempu = u.clone();`.  Same goes for tempv, of course.

Comment: @VGR Thank you, it's working well, I think! I think you could make this comment as an answer, to let me accept it.

Comment: In the future please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I will try to make my next question better, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you intended `tempu` and `tempv` to hold copies of the original `u` and `v` arrays.  However, merely assigning a different variable to the array with `tempu = u;` does not copy the array;  since arrays are objects, that assignment merely places another reference to the same array in `tempu`.

To copy an array, use:

```
tempu = u.clone();
tempv = v.clone();
```